# How to share authentication between mobile app and webview?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I was wondering and trying to find a solution to open webview inside mobile application with the same authentication session or same users without any user interaction.

Now I was already implemented login for mobile with Oauth but if I have no idea to implement like the mentioned above with correctly solution.

I have some solutions, but not sure it is the best practice and good for security.

1. I will generate an authorized URL with a new client different from a mobile app for the button in the app but in this case have a chance to allow the user log in with a different account if the user doesn't know that. It will make a mismatch between mobile and webview.
2. I will pass id_token instead and let webview validate id_token with a public key if valid force login for webview.

FYI, I have implemented OIDC, too but sure not I can use it to support this case or not.

Answer (score 6):

A web view is a private browser session, so typically the SSO cookie used for the mobile sign in will not be remembered, leading to a double login. These days, migrating web views to native views is the preferred option, though that can be a lot of work in some cases.

**NONCE PATTERN**

There is an interesting OAuth pattern that could possibly be used. Before invoking the web view, the mobile app can send its ID token as a proof, to an endpoint that issues a `nonce`. This is a short lived (~30 seconds) random value that can only be used once. It is therefore OK to send it in a query parameter to the web app.

When the web app receives a nonce it issues an OpenID Connect redirect, supplying the nonce in the `login_hint_token` parameter. A nonce custom authentication method is also supplied in `acr_values`. The nonce is validated, and on success, a new set of tokens are issued to the web client, with the subject from the mobile client's ID token, and with the web app's scopes and claims.

At Curity, where I work, we produced an [article](https://curity.io/resources/learn/nonce-authenticator-pattern/) on this security design pattern which some readers might find useful.

**SUMMARY**

This pattern keeps tokens between different apps separated, and avoids sending long lived tokens in browser URLs. The ID token bootstraps a session, which is a common use for it.

It also deals well with the fact that OAuth secured mobile apps use tokens, whereas browser based apps mostly use secure HTTP only cookies. The security is reasonable also, though it is always worth thinking through threats.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this mechanism sharing authentication between the mobile app and WebView two years ago, and it's been running well since then. I'll summarize what I've done below. I realized I had made a little simplified NONCE PATTERN by checking Gary Archer's above answer. But it still has some value for others' reference, I hope.

[image: the sequence diagram]

In summary, the solution is something like the above sequence diagram. We generate a short-lived authCode (nonce) for each user on demand, and the WebView depends on its own BFF to do every talk with the auth server and other domain services.