# Approach to have a SSO like flow in mobile app web view for accessing web pages after authentication using OIDC

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, single-sign-on, openid-connect

Have implemented `OAuth2` based authentication flow using `open id connect` in our cross platform mobile application.

Need to access web pages within our mobile app web view/ browser but the mobile web view doesn't maintain any session after the authentication flow. The web pages that we need to access asks for login authentication again whenever we try to open any url within our web view/ browser.

Have tried some approach like passing in auth token in web page request header and through appending it in the url but it doesn't work. it needs all the session details in order to work.

We are using `Xamarin.Forms` and [IdentityModel.OidcClient](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient) Nuget package for OIDC authentication.

Is there a way to access all the session details from the web browser when we authenticate and pass that information to the web view whenever we try to open any web page or URL?

I know MSAL library does support something like this but it only works with Azure AD based IDP and we are using salesforce based IDP.

Comment: That's a tricky problem - [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74832802/how-to-share-authentication-between-mobile-app-and-webview/74842376#74842376) may give you some pointers though.