# How to implement SSO with micro front-end architecture where native apps use refresh tokens

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, auth0, refresh-token

At the company I work for, we have some web SPAs (Single Page Applications), as well as native apps for iOS and Android.

For the SPAs, we've been following a micro front-end architecture, and we want to start adding some of these micro front-ends into our native apps as well, so that we're not building the same functionality multiple times on the front-end.

The micro front-end implementation strategy will differ between SPAs and native apps. For SPAs we're using [Webpack module federation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/), whereas for native apps we're intending to use WebViews.

For the SPAs, authentication and SSO is pretty straight forward - users authenticate to our IDP (Auth0) using their credentials in a browser based flow (specifically authorization code flow with PKCE). Micro front-ends SPAs also authenticate to our IDP using the same approach, however given it all occurs in (the same) browser, SSO kicks in and the user is transparently authenticated without having to explicitly log in with their credentials. Essentially how this works is that on the initial auth, the IDP sends an auth cookie to the browser that will be detected by subsequent authentication attempts by micro front-ends in the same browser - when a micro front-end redirects to the IDPs `/authorize` endpoint, the user is transparently authenticated without having to explicitly log in with their credentials.

Back to native apps- SSO with micro front-ends in WebViews works fine when the initial auth in the native app redirects to the IDPs `/authorize` endpoint (in an in-app browser tab) and the user authenticates with their credentials. The problem arises with refresh tokens. Our native apps leverage refresh tokens to streamline the auth process i.e. allowing users to authenticate using biometrics (e.g. thumb print) or PIN instead of explicit user credentials. The refresh token exchange is just a standard API invocation - it doesn't open a browser window and therefore doesn't receive an updated auth cookie. When the native app subsequently opens a micro front-end in a WebView the user will be required to re-authenticate, which is a negative in terms of the UX.

I'm pretty sure we're not the first team to encounter this. Just wondering how others have dealt with this scenario?

EDIT: the advice that's been given WRT WebViews in native apps is that we don't have access to persistent cookies (or at least there's some limitations). Therefore there's potentially issues with SSO irrespective of whether auth was via a browser-based flow with user credentials, or refresh token exchange.

Comment: My [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74832802/how-to-share-authentication-between-mobile-app-and-webview) on sending a nonce from the mobile app to the webview may give you some ideas.