# Make a user login to a Web app from Mobile App

Tags: android, security, single-sign-on, openid-connect, pkce

How can we make a user logged in a Mobile App also sign in to a Web app. I have a partner's mobile app that has a link to a dashboard in our web app. When consumer click on the "dashboard" link on Mobile App, I can pass user id through a query string, but I am wondering how can I make them sign in to our Web app without going through another Login screen. I have read a bit about SSO, is that right direction I am thinking towards? I see that SSO is used for multiple Web apps, but I don't know if I can leverage that concept for Mobile App and Web App scenario. If you came across any article/post describing more on this specific behavior, please share.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve SSO there are prerequisites on how login is implemented. The 2 factors are `identity provider session cookies` and `cookie jars`.

**LOGIN FLOWS**

The general login flow is App to Authorization Server (AS) to Identity Provider (IDP). To enable SSO, users must login via the same IDP, though they can use a different AS.

**ANDROID**

Typically an Android app implements login using a Chrome Custom Tab. Whereas a web app is invoked in the Chrome browser. These share the same cookies.

**IOS**

Typically an iOS app implements login using an ASWebAuthenticationSession window. Whereas a web app is invoked in the Safari browser. These do not share the same cookies.

**ADVANCED OPTIONS**

An advanced option is for the source mobile application to issue a nonce at the target application's AS, then pass the nonce to the web app. My [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74832802/how-to-share-authentication-between-mobile-app-and-webview/74842376#74842376) has some details on that.